# No se están insertando en la base los datos de un formulario

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

Estoy realizando un sistema de inventarios lo cual utilizo PHP y SQL Server 2008. Al realizar una conexión a la base de datos todo es exitoso, pero al ingresar datos en los formularios desde PHP no inserta ningún dato a la base.

```
<?php

    $serverName = ("Localhost"); //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (por defecto es 1433
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"new", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
    $conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    //include('conexion.php');

    if($conexion===false)
    {
        die(print_r (sqlsrv_errors(),true));

    }



    if ($_POST) 

   {
      $id_usuario_final =$_POST['id_usuario_final'];
      $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
      $ap =$_POST['ap'];
      $am=$_POST['am'];
      $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
      $localidad=$_POST['localidad'];
      $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];

      $tsql= "INSERT into 'new.Usuarios' (id_usuario_final,nombre,ap,am,fecha,localidad,departamento) 
      values ('$id_usuario_final','$nombre,'$ap','$am','$fecha','$localidad','$departamento')";

     $param1=array($id_usuario_final,$nombre,$ap,$am,$fecha,$localidad,$departamento);

     $recurso=sqlsrv_query($tsql,$param1);

     sqlsrv_close($connectionInfo);



   }
?>

<html>
<head>

<body>


<form name="pru"  method="post"><br></br>



<center><fieldset style="width:30%" "width:600px">

<td>
    <legend>Información de Usuarios</legend>

    <div><br>

       <label>ID Usuario:</label></th>
        <input type="text" name="id_usuario_final"
         </br>
          </div>

     <div><br>

       <label>Nombre:</label></th>
        <input type="text" name="nombre"
         </br>
          </div>

      <div><br>
       <label >Apellido Paterno:</label>
        <input type="text" name="ap"
         </br>
          </div>



      <div><br>
       <label>Apellido Materno:</label>
        <input type="text" name="am"                                                                
         </br>
          </div>



        <div><br>
         <label>Fecha:</label>
          <input type="date" name="fecha"
           </br>
            </div>


        <div><br>
         <label>Localidad:</label>
          <input type="text" name="localidad"
           </br>
            </div>

        <div><br>
         <label>Departamento:</label>
          <input type="text" name="departamento"
           </br>
            </div>


</td><center></fieldset><br></br>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué está dividido en 3 partes? ¿O dónde se referencian entre sí?... Y mucho más importante ¿podrías agregar una descripción mostrando qué pasos hiciste para depurarlo y qué resultados estás obteniendo?

Comment: Todos son de un mismo codigo, lo dividi asi por que la misma pagina lo pedia (es la primera vez que la utilizo) pero todo el codigo es parat de uno

Comment: Creo que no adjunte el código correctamente. Ejecutándolo y teniéndolo en orden se apreciaría mucho mejor.

Comment: siempre estás a tiempo de [edit] la pregunta y ordenar bien el código. Luego de pegar el código, hay que seleccionarlo completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`. (o Ctrl+K)

Comment: Es la primera vez que visito esta pagina y la verdad no tengo muy clara la idea de como se utilice. ¿Tienes algún correo electrónico para adjuntar el código correctamente?

Comment: Solo coloque el HTML eliminando PHP Y BOOTSTRAP, espero este bien.

Comment: Ahora ya lo edite adjuntándole el código en PHP, con la conexión a la base de datos (llamada new).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba modificando la linea:

```
$tsql= "INSERT into 'new.Usuarios' (id_usuario_final,nombre,ap,am,fecha,localidad,departamento) 
  values ('$id_usuario_final','$nombre,'$ap','$am','$fecha','$localidad','$departamento')";
```

por esta:

```
$tsql= "INSERT into Usuarios (id_usuario_final,nombre,ap,am,fecha,localidad,departamento) 
  values ('$id_usuario_final','$nombre,'$ap','$am','$fecha','$localidad','$departamento')";
```

**Edit:** Otra cosa. La columna **id_usuario_final** es un dato tipo *Int*? En ese caso, deberías sacar las comillas en el String **$tsql**.

Exitos!